# Appveyor fails on R-devel but passes on R-release

Tags: r, appveyor

I cannot get my R package passing appveyor on R-devel (it passes on R-release fine). The issue started on a nightly build with nothing changed from the previous, passing build.

The error in `00install.out` is "Error : package 'gtools' was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version".

Here's my appveror.yml

```
# Download script file from GitHub
init:
  ps: |
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
        Invoke-WebRequest http://raw.github.com/krlmlr/r-appveyor/master/scripts/appveyor-tool.ps1 -OutFile "..\appveyor-tool.ps1"
        Import-Module '..\appveyor-tool.ps1'
install:
  ps: Bootstrap


# Adapt as necessary starting from here
services:
  - mssql2012sp1

build_script:
  - ps: iex .\inst\CIDatabase\CIBuild_DBCreate.ps1
  - travis-tool.sh install_deps

test_script:
  - travis-tool.sh run_tests

on_failure:
  - 7z a failure.zip *.Rcheck\*
  - appveyor PushArtifact failure.zip

environment:
  global:
    R_CHECK_ARGS: "--no-manual --as-cran --run-donttest"
    WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS: 1

  matrix:
    - R_VERSION: release
      R_ARCH: x64

    - R_VERSION: devel
      R_ARCH: x64

    - R_VERSION: release
      R_ARCH: i386

    - R_VERSION: devel
      R_ARCH: i386

artifacts:
  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.log'
    name: Logs

  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.out'
    name: Logs

  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.fail'
    name: Logs

  - path: '*.Rcheck\**\*.Rout'
    name: Logs

  - path: '\*_*.tar.gz'
    name: Bits

  - path: '\*_*.zip'
    name: Bits
```

Comment: If any help, I've seen that too for my packages. I haven't troubleshooted so I don't know the cause, but could be correlated with R devel recently changed the internal SEXP structure (to support ALTREP) and if so affects packages that user native code. If so, a solution might be to force installing from source, but not sure how easy that is on AppVeyor. (I'll just wait it out myself.)

Comment: If nothing changed between last good and first bad build, then this is most probably external dependency. If you share links to those builds, we can find more.

Comment: Thanks @ilyaf. Here's a [recent build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/CatalystAdmin/healthcareai-r/build/1.0.1652) with the issue, and here is when it switched: [last passing](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/CatalystAdmin/healthcareai-r/build/1.0.1239) and [first failing](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/CatalystAdmin/healthcareai-r/build/1.0.1241)

Comment: Seems like this is important difference between logs -- **passing:** `using R Under development (unstable) (2017-09-11 r73238)`, **failing:** `using R Under development (unstable) (2017-09-14 r73268)`.